# How to remove a row in a dataframe if the entry of a specific column is numeric

Tags: python, pandas

It is not difficult to remove a row in a dataframe according to the fact that a specific column is non numerical.

But in my case I have the opposite: I must remove the lines which correspond to a numerical entry of a specific column.

Comment: Could you please share your DataFrame and indicate your goal on it?

Answer (score 0):

Convert column to numeric with `errors='coerce'` and test missing values for remove numeric values:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data={'tested col': [1,'b',2,'3'],
                       'A': [1,2,3,4]})

print (df)

  tested col  A
0          1  1
1          b  2
2          2  3
3          3  4

df1 = df[pd.to_numeric(df['tested col'], errors='coerce').isna()]
print (df1)
  tested col  A
1          b  2
```